# Optimize query mongodb/mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

```
class Job
  field :occupation, :type => String
  field :experience, :type => String
end
```

In my api file:

```
get :searches do
  Cv.search({query: "*#{params[:q]}*"}).map{ |cv| {id: cv.id, text: cv.occupation } }
end
```

This generate a json file:

```
[{"id":"513dbb61a61654a845000005","text":"industrial engineer"},{"id":"513a11d4a6165411b2000008","text":"javascript engineer"}]
```

I'm using mongodb as database and mongoid as orm/odm.

**This working fine with 10 or 100 or 1000 results but my question is if is possible optimize the api query for large data collections **1.000.000*** or **2.000.000** of results.*

Comment: Perhaps this might help: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/optimization/

Comment: Thank you, can you paste a example with mongoid? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your query, if you want to query on `occupation` you need to create an index on `occupation`

```
class Job
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :occupation, :type => String
  field :experience, :type => String
  index({ occupation: 1 })
end
```

Mongoid automatically creates and index on `_id` so if you always include that in your query it will remain fast, unless your database indexes starts exceeding available ram.

`Job.where(:occupation => "javascript engineer")` will use the index